# Php search string (with wildcards)

Tags: php, wildcard

Is there a way to put a wildcard in a string? The reason why I am asking is because currently I have a function to search for a substring between two substrings (i.e grab the contents between "my" and "has fleas" in the sentence "my dog has fleas", resulting in "dog").

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){ 
    $string = " ".$string; 
    $ini = strpos($string,$start); 
    if ($ini == 0) return ""; 
    $ini += strlen($start); 
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini; 
    return substr($string,$ini,$len); 
}
```

What I want to do is have it search with a wildcard in the string. So say I search between "%WILDCARD%" and "has fleas" in the sentence "My dog has fleas" - it would still output "dog".

I don't know if I explained it too well but hopefully someone will understand me :P. Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: if you want wildcards, you can use regular expressions instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where regular expressions are actually helpful. :)

```
if (preg_match('/my (\w+) has/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

See the documentation for [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: That's just ignorant, regular expressions are excellent tools.

Comment: @Raveren: Regular expressions are terrible tools in the hand of fools. Way to many people use them without understanding their limitations, what kind of engines exist, etc.

Comment: *Regular expressions are terrible tools in the hand of fools.* So is literally every other tool in existence.

Comment: I don't know of any other (programmer) tool that is so often misused.

Comment: @LukášLalinský can you blame us? The syntax for regular expressions is pretty ugly. There is literally not one time I use a reg ex without Googling it

Answer (score 8):

wildcard pattern could be converted to regex pattern like this

```
function wildcard_match($pattern, $subject) {
  $pattern = strtr($pattern, array(
    '*' => '.*?', // 0 or more (lazy) - asterisk (*)
    '?' => '.', // 1 character - question mark (?)
  ));
  return preg_match("/$pattern/", $subject);
}
```

if string contents special characters, e.g. \.+*?^$|{}/'#, they should be \-escaped

don't tested:

```
function wildcard_match($pattern, $subject) {
  // quotemeta function has most similar behavior,
  // it escapes \.+*?^$[](), but doesn't escape |{}/'#
  // we don't include * and ?
  $special_chars = "\.+^$[]()|{}/'#";
  $special_chars = str_split($special_chars);
  $escape = array();
  foreach ($special_chars as $char) $escape[$char] = "\\$char";
  $pattern = strtr($pattern, $escape);
  $pattern = strtr($pattern, array(
    '*' => '.*?', // 0 or more (lazy) - asterisk (*)
    '?' => '.', // 1 character - question mark (?)
  ));
  return preg_match("/$pattern/", $subject);
}
```

Comment: There should be possible a preg_quote arround at the $pattern

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex.

```
$string = "My dog has fleas";
if (preg_match("/\S+ (\S+) has fleas/", $string, $matches))
  echo ($matches[1]);
else
  echo ("Not found");
```

`\S` means any non-space character, `+` means one or more of the previous thing, so `\S+` means match one or more non-space characters. `(…)` means capture the content of the submatch and put into the `$matches` array.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that regex are much more flexible than wildcards, but sometimes all you want is a simple way to define patterns. For people looking for a portable solution (not *NIX only) here is my implementation of the function:

```
function wild_compare($wild, $string) {
    $wild_i = 0;
    $string_i = 0;

    $wild_len = strlen($wild);
    $string_len = strlen($string);

    while ($string_i < $string_len && $wild[$wild_i] != '*') {
        if (($wild[$wild_i] != $string[$string_i]) && ($wild[$wild_i] != '?')) {
            return 0;
        }
        $wild_i++;
        $string_i++;
    }

    $mp = 0;
    $cp = 0;

    while ($string_i < $string_len) {
        if ($wild[$wild_i] == '*') {
            if (++$wild_i == $wild_len) {
                return 1;
            }
            $mp = $wild_i;
            $cp = $string_i + 1;
        }
        else
        if (($wild[$wild_i] == $string[$string_i]) || ($wild[$wild_i] == '?')) {
            $wild_i++;
            $string_i++;
        }
        else {
            $wild_i = $mp;
            $string_i = $cp++;
        }
    }

    while ($wild[$wild_i] == '*') {
        $wild_i++;
    }

    return $wild_i == $wild_len ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Naturally the PHP implementation is slower than fnmatch(), but it would work on any platform.

It can be used like this:

```
if (wild_compare('regex are * useful', 'regex are always useful') == 1) {
    echo "I'm glad we agree on this";
}
```

Comment: nice!  we had a requirement to allow our staff to enter regular expression rules to match up certain pieces of data.  As they don't understand regex, this was the perfect solution!

Answer (score 3):

If you insist to use a wildcard (and yes, PREG is much better) you can use the function
[fnmatch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php).

ex:

```php
if (fnmatch('my * has', $str)) { }
```

Comment: For now, this function is not available on non-POSIX compliant systems except Windows. So it works on Windows, now.

Comment: @Moradnejad that is true, I'll edit my message so it might help someone else!

Comment: LOL. I didn't expect you this fast on a 10-year-old answer.