# Wildcard PHP text search

Tags: php, search, text

I have a text string that has been doctored to be web safe URLs i.e. non alphanumeric's are converted to "_".

What I want to do is search for the original name before it was converted, this means that I need some kind of wild card search i.e.

**What I have**

```
test__mytest
```

**With wildcards**

```
test??mytest
```

**The string I would find with the wildcard search**

```
test: mytest
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this in PHP?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305362/php-search-string-with-wildcards)
I'll update if I get it to work.

Edit: Here is my solution

```
$searchstring = "/".str_replace("_","(.?)", escape_string_for_regex($match))."/";
```

This replaces all _'s with a search for a single character in that place.
I then use the following line to test $searchstring against the test string.

```
if (preg_match($searchstring, $matchtitle))
```

Comment: escape_string_for_regex should be `preg_quote($match, '/')`. (Unless you are using that inside your own function).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be encoding the special characters instead of transforming them to underscores. Then you wouldn't need wildcards, you would just search for the encoded value.

For example test%3A%20page

This would also prevent the problem you would encounter if you tried convert the following two into pages:

test:page
test!page

They would both get turned into test_page, and the space/time continuum would be in danger. Probably unlikely, but still undesirable.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the encoding so I have to use wilcards. Thanks though